# ath10k/pre-cal wifi firmware missing

Tags: linux, wifi, binary, firmware, pci

I tried installing linux on my computer. During the `Detect network hardware` stage, the installer warned that non-free firmware files were missing, `ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:01:0.0.bin` and `ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:0.0.bin`. Although my installer was bundled with the entire non-free firmware directory the files were still missing. I browsed https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174 but was unable to find them. Are there any scripts/packages that can enable wifi or am I stuck with no wifi on this computer forever?

Comment: Please, specify which linux distribution you installng.

Comment: For example look at Ubuntu solutions https://askubuntu.com/q/607707/67144
For Your distribution folder for firmwares can differ.